# How to read .csv file that contains utf-8 values by pandas dataframe

Tags: csv, python-3.x, pandas, utf-8

I'm trying to read .csv file that contains utf-8 data in some of its columns. The method of reading is by using pandas dataframe. The code is as following:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Cancer_training.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

Then I got the following examples of errors with different files:

(1) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 14:invalid continuation byte

(2) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc9 in position 3:invalid continuation byte

Could you please share your ideas and experience with such problem? Thank you.

[python: 3.4.1.final.0, 
pandas: 0.14.1]

sample of the raw data, I cannot put full record because of the legal restrictions of the medical data:

[image]

Comment: Can you post some raw data, also what version pandas, python are you using?

Comment: Many thanks for your quick reply. I have already updated my question. Looking forward for your kindly feedback.

Comment: That is the unicode for degree symbol, this actually works fine on my machine, you can anonymize the data and just include the problematic lines, just need your raw data to reproduce your issue. Note that the parser is complaining about a different encoding: http://www.codetable.net/hex/cf and http://www.codetable.net/hex/c9

Comment: Many thanks for your helpful reply. Actually, I tried different python and panda versions but still I get the same error with different encoding. My issue is that the number of lines around 40000 * different files with different encoding, and handling such amount of data would be time consuming. Do you suggest another way by which the .csv files prepared to be readable in pandas where the utf-8 values changed to be for example strings? Again, many thanks for you appreciated time.

Comment: How is this csv generated? It may be better to fix the source rather than try cleaning up at the reading stage, the alternative is to use a file reader, read the lines in and decode them

Comment: Hello again. I'm sorry to be late in my reply. I was stuck with my data. I will continue with my problem to be solved with considering your appreciated suggestions. I will back tomorrow to report what I ended up with. Have a nice evening Mr EdChum.

Comment: I hope that you are fine. I just want to report what I ended up with. Actually, I tried all different encoding because I thought what I have in my datasets may not even be utf-8 and still having the problem. However, I decided to clean my data by using regular expression for some of datasets and simple python code for the other. Again, many thanks for your comments and time.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem for no apparent reason, I managed to get it work using this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

not sure why though

Comment: I did this and it worked, not sure why either

Answer (score 1):

I've also done as Irh09 proposed but the second file it read it was wrongly decoded  and couldn't find a column with tildes (á, é, í, ó, ú).

So I recomend encapsulating the error like this:

```
try:
    df = pd.read_csv('file', encoding = "utf-8")
except:
    df = pd.read_csv('file', encoding= "ISO-8859-1")
```